# Unable to run Flutter code in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, flutter, dart

**I get an error everytime I try to run the default code that flutter provides for a new project**

````
> java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class org.gradle.internal.compiler.java.ClassNameCollector (in unnamed module @0x1da59d23) cannot access class com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$TypeSymbol (in module jdk.compiler) because module jdk.compiler does not export com.sun.tools.javac.code to unnamed module @0x1da59d23```
````

Any tips?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jXm2v.jpg (I have run flutter doctor and this is the result after fixing the licenses)

Comment: 1st run `flutter doctor`

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/4jUuL59 here are the results

Comment: there are some steps missing on installation side. please follow https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install

Comment: for the license step, just simply run the given command i.e : `flutter doctor --android-licenses` and follow the instructions!

Comment: Alright thanks for the help I'll try it out

Comment: I still get the same error